# Within C++ functions, how are Rcpp objects passed to other functions (by reference or by copy)?

Tags: r, performance, pointers, rcpp

I've just finished writing a new version of the ABCoptim package using Rcpp. With around 30x speed ups, I'm very happy with the new version's performance (vs old version), but I'm still having some concerns on if I have space to improve performance without modifying too much the code.

Within the main function of ABCoptim (written in C++) I'm passing around a Rcpp::List object containing "bees positions" (NumericMatrix) and some NumericVectors with important information for the algorithm itself. My question is, when I'm passing a Rcpp::List object around other functions, e.g.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

List ABCinit([some input]){[some code here]};
void ABCfun2(List x){[some code here]};
void ABCfun3(List x){[some code here]};

List ABCmain([some input])
{
  List x = ABCinit([some input]);
  while ([some statement])
  {
    ABCfun2(x);
    ABCfun3(x);
  }
  ...

  return List::create(x["results"]);
}
```

What does Rcpp does within the while loop? Does the x object is passed by reference or by deep copy to the functions `ABCfun2` and `ABCfun3`? I've seen the usage of 'const List&x', which tells me that I can pass Rcpp objects using pointers, but the thing is that I need this list to be variable (and no constant), is there anyway to improve this? I'm afraid that iterative copy of this x List can be slowing down my code.

PS: I'm still new to C++, furthermore I'm using Rcpp to learn C++.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no deep copy in Rcpp unless you ask for it with `clone`. When you pass by value, you are making a new `List` object but it uses the same underlying R object.

So the different is small between pass by value and pass by reference.

However, when you pass by value, you have to pay the price for protecting the underlying object one more time. It might incur extra cost as for this Rcpp relies on the recursive not very efficient `R_PreserveObject`.

My guideline would be to pass by reference whenever possible so that you don't pay extra protecting price. If you know that `ABCfun2` won't change the object, I'd advise passing by reference to const : `ABCfun2( const List& )`. If you are going to make changes to the `List`, then I'd recommend using `ABCfun2( List& )`.

Consider this code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp  ;

#define DBG(MSG,X) Rprintf("%20s SEXP=<%p>. List=%p\n", MSG, (SEXP)X, &X ) ;

void fun_copy( List x, const char* idx ){
    x[idx] = "foo" ;
    DBG( "in fun_copy: ", x) ;

}
void fun_ref( List& x, const char* idx ){
    x[idx] = "bar" ;
    DBG( "in fun_ref: ", x) ;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_copy(){

    // create a list of 3 components
    List data = List::create( _["a"] = 1, _["b"] = 2 ) ;
    DBG( "initial: ", data) ;

    fun_copy( data, "a") ;
    DBG( "\nafter fun_copy (1): ", data) ;

    // alter the 1st component of ths list, passed by value
    fun_copy( data, "d") ;
    DBG( "\nafter fun_copy (2): ", data) ;


}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_ref(){

    // create a list of 3 components
    List data = List::create( _["a"] = 1, _["b"] = 2 ) ;
    DBG( "initial: ", data) ;

    fun_ref( data, "a") ;
    DBG( "\nafter fun_ref (1): ", data) ;

    // alter the 1st component of ths list, passed by value
    fun_ref( data, "d") ;
    DBG( "\nafter fun_ref (2): ", data) ;


}
```

All I'm doing is pass a list to a function, update it and print some information about the pointer to the underlying R object and the pointer to the List object ( `this` ) .

Here are the results of what happens when I call `test_copy` and `test_ref`:

```
> test_copy()
           initial:  SEXP=<0x7ff97c26c278>. List=0x7fff5b909fd0
       in fun_copy:  SEXP=<0x7ff97c26c278>. List=0x7fff5b909f30

after fun_copy (1):  SEXP=<0x7ff97c26c278>. List=0x7fff5b909fd0
$a
[1] "foo"

$b
[1] 2

       in fun_copy:  SEXP=<0x7ff97b2b3ed8>. List=0x7fff5b909f20

after fun_copy (2):  SEXP=<0x7ff97c26c278>. List=0x7fff5b909fd0
$a
[1] "foo"

$b
[1] 2
```

We start with an existing list associated with an R object.

```
           initial:  SEXP=<0x7fda4926d278>. List=0x7fff5bb5efd0
```

We pass it by value to `fun_copy` so we get a new `List` but using the same underlying R object:

```
       in fun_copy:  SEXP=<0x7fda4926d278>. List=0x7fff5bb5ef30
```

We exit of `fun_copy`. same underlying R object again, and back to our original `List` :

```
after fun_copy (1):  SEXP=<0x7fda4926d278>. List=0x7fff5bb5efd0
```

Now we call again `fun_copy` but this time updating a component that was not on the list: `x["d"]="foo"`.

```
       in fun_copy:  SEXP=<0x7fda48989120>. List=0x7fff5bb5ef20
```

`List` had no choice but to create itself a new underlying R object, but this object is only underlying to the local `List`. Therefore when we get out of `get_copy`, we are back to our original `List` with its original underlying `SEXP`.

```
after fun_copy (2):  SEXP=<0x7fda4926d278>. List=0x7fff5bb5efd0
```

The key thing here is that the first time `"a"` was already on the list, so we updated the data directly. Because the local object to `fun_copy` and the outer object from `test_copy` share the same underlying R object, modifications inside `fun_copy` was propagated.

The second time, `fun_copy` grows its local `List` object, associating it with a brand new `SEXP` which does not propagate to the outer function.

Now consider what happens when you pass by reference :

```
> test_ref()
           initial:  SEXP=<0x7ff97c0e0f80>. List=0x7fff5b909fd0
        in fun_ref:  SEXP=<0x7ff97c0e0f80>. List=0x7fff5b909fd0

  after fun_ref(1):  SEXP=<0x7ff97c0e0f80>. List=0x7fff5b909fd0
$a
[1] "bar"

$b
[1] 2

        in fun_ref:  SEXP=<0x7ff97b5254c8>. List=0x7fff5b909fd0

  after fun_ref(2):  SEXP=<0x7ff97b5254c8>. List=0x7fff5b909fd0
$a
[1] "bar"

$b
[1] 2

$d
[1] "bar"
```

There is only one `List` object `0x7fff5b909fd0`. When we have to get a new `SEXP` in the second call, it correctly gets propagated to the outer level.

To me, the behavior you get when passing by references is much easier to reason with.

Comment: That's very clear to me now! Thanks Romain and Dirk! Both of your advices have been very useful. Big fan of Rcpp trying to show it to the spanish-speaking world http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/16153_7d5a52078aa24b3da140e3f94e48226b.html#/ =) Thanks!

Comment: Good post.  Could you add some measurements over a (large enough) number of calls to see what the actual cost is?

Answer (score 13):

Briefly:

1. `void ABCfun(List x)` passes *by value* but then again `List` is an Rcpp object wrapping a `SEXP` which is a pointer -- so the cost *here* is less than what a C++ programmer would suspect and it is in fact lightweight. (But as Romain rightly points out, there is cost in an extra protection layer.)
2. `void ABCfun(const List x)` promises not to change `x`, but again because it is a pointer...
3. `void ABCfun(const List & x)` looks most normal to a C++ programmer and is supported in Rcpp since last year.

Ipso facto, in the Rcpp context all three are about the same.  But you should think along the lines of best C++ practice and prefer 3. as one day you may use a `std::list<....>` instead in which case the const reference clearly is preferable (Scott Meyers has an entire post about this in *Effective C++* (or maybe in the companion *More Effective C++*).

But the most important lesson is that you should not just believe what people tell you on the internet, but rather measure and profile whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to `Rcpp` so figured i'd answer @Dirk's request for a measurement of the cost of the two passing styles (copy and reference) ...

There is surprisingly little difference -- between the two approaches.

I get the below:

```
microbenchmark(test_copy(), test_ref(), times = 1e6)
Unit: microseconds
        expr   min    lq     mean median    uq        max neval cld
  test_copy() 5.102 5.566 7.518406  6.030 6.494 106615.653 1e+06   a
   test_ref() 4.639 5.566 7.262655  6.029 6.494   5794.319 1e+06   a
```

I used a cut-down version of @Roman's code: removing the `DBG` calls.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

void fun_copy( List x, const char* idx){
    x[idx] = "foo";
}

void fun_ref( List& x, const char* idx){
    x[idx] = "bar";
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test_copy(){

    // create a list of 3 components
    List data = List::create( _["a"] = 1, _["b"] = 2);

    // alter the 1st component of the list, passed by value
    fun_copy( data, "a");

    // add a 3rd component to the list
    fun_copy( data, "d");
    return(data);

}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test_ref(){

    // create a list of 3 components
    List data = List::create( _["a"] = 1, _["b"] = 2);

    // alter the 1st component of the list, passed by reference
    fun_ref( data, "a");

    // add a 3rd component to the list
    fun_ref( data, "d");
    return(data);

}

/*** R

# benchmark copy v. ref functions
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(test_copy(), test_ref(), times = 1e6)

*/
```