# Declare a variable as a reference in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, rcpp11

In C++, we can declare a variable as a reference.

```
int a = 10;
int& b = a;
```

If we set `b=15`, `a` also changes.

I want to do the similar thing in Rcpp.

```
List X = obj_from_R["X"];
IntegerVector x_i = X[index];
x_i = value;
```

I want to update an object from R called `X` by inserting a value to one of its vector. The code above did not work, so I tried this:

```
IntegerVector& x_i = X[index];
```

and received an error.

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'IntegerVector'
      (aka 'Vector<13>') cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Proxy' (aka 'generic_proxy<19>')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Within C++ functions, how are Rcpp objects passed to other functions (by reference or by copy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112893/within-c-functions-how-are-rcpp-objects-passed-to-other-functions-by-referen)

Answer (score 13):

This question gets asked a lot in differing variants.

Here are some popular answers:

1. [Within C++ functions, how are Rcpp objects passed to other functions (by reference or by copy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112893/within-c-functions-how-are-rcpp-objects-passed-to-other-functions-by-referen)
2. [Update Rcpp::NumericMatrix passed by reference using RcppArmadillo submat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43962398/update-rcppnumericmatrix-passed-by-reference-using-rcpparmadillo-submat)
3. [Rcpp pass by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300048/rcpp-pass-by-reference-vs-by-value)
4. [Passing by reference a data.frame and updating it with rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731106/passing-by-reference-a-data-frame-and-updating-it-with-rcpp)
5. [Rcpp Update matrix passed by reference and return the update in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087970/rcpp-update-matrix-passed-by-reference-and-return-the-update-in-r)
6. [Passing large matrices to RcppArmadillo function without creating copy (advanced constructors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866130/passing-large-matrices-to-rcpparmadillo-function-without-creating-copy-advanced)
7. [Rcpp: Inconsistent behavior with proxy model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344257/rcpp-inconsistent-behavior-with-proxy-model)
8. [Why is my Rcpp implementation for finding the number of unique items slower than base R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024568/why-is-my-rcpp-implementation-for-finding-the-number-of-unique-items-slower-than)

---

More details...

From the FAQ entry **[Rcpp changed the (const) object I passed by value](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf#page=10)** that I wrote:

> *Rcpp* objects are wrappers around the underlying *R* objects' SEXP, or S-expression. The `SEXP` is a pointer variable that holds the location of where the *R* object data has been stored *R:Internals*. That is to say, the `SEXP` does not hold the actual data of the *R* object but merely a reference to where the data resides. When creating a new *Rcpp* object for an *R* object to enter *C++*, this object will use the same SEXP that powers the original *R* object if the types match otherwise a new SEXP must be created to be type safe. In essence, the underlying SEXP objects are passed by reference without explicit copies being made into *C++*. We refer to this arrangement as a proxy model.

So, the `&` is just visual sugar as *Rcpp* objects already act as references.

Thus, the following would show the conclusion:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void show_references(Rcpp::List X, 
                     Rcpp::IntegerVector y, 
                     int index = 0) {
  X[index] = y;
}
```

Example:

```
y_vec = c(-1L, 8L, 12L)
X_list = list(a = c(0L, 2L, 3L), b = c(42L, 50L, 30L))
X_list
# $a
# [1] 0 2 3
#
# $b
# [1] 42 50 30

show_references(X_list, y_vec)
X_list
# $a
# [1] -1  8 12
#
# $b
# [1] 42 50 30
```

The following *Rcpp* proxy model slides I created should further illustrate what is happening

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Source: https://twitter.com/axiomsofxyz/status/938881541396197377

Comment: Nice anser and upvoted but ... let's call it a duplicate.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40899379#40899379

Comment: Does this mean if I write `NumericVector X = list_obj_from_R["X"]; X[index] = 5;`, I can insert `5` to the specified index in R object (`X`) without explicitly returning  `list_obj_from_R`?

Comment: @user51966 not quite. What happens when you pull an object out from a list is a deep clone. The object has to be reinserted into the list to receive the reference update.